# hevm doesn't see file

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts, dapptools, hevm

When running a 'seth call' that crashes and puts me into the hevm debugger, after putting in my etherscan API key, I get:
`hevm: @openzeppelin/contracts/drafts/IERC20Permit.sol: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`. I manually copied such a file into a `draft` directory I mkdir'ed and pasted in a node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/drafts/IERC20Permit.sol, but it still doesn't work. Any idea why?

You can reproduce this by installing dapptools and calling `seth call --debug 0x68b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45 <txdata, for example 0x0>`.